# Structuring Overtone project

Tags: clojure, overtone

I'm just getting started with Overtone, but I want to keep things somewhat organised from the start.

***`project.clj:`***

```
(defproject overtone-sketchbook "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [overtone "0.9.1"]])
```

***`src/overtone_sketchbook/synths.clj:`***

```
(ns overtone-sketchbook.synths
  (:use [overtone.live]))

(definst pluck-saw [f 800 d 3]
         (* (saw (+ 100 (* 200 (saw d))))
            (pluck (* (white-noise)
                      (env-gen (perc 0.001 2) :action FREE))
                   1 3 (/ 1 f))))
```

#### *REPL session 1:*

```
> lein repl
nREPL server started on port 52425
REPL-y 0.2.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)

user=> (use 'overtone.live)
--> Loading Overtone...
  ********************************************************** 
       WARNING: JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may 
       lead to reduced performance. This happens to currently be the 
       default lein setting:

       https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/pull/1230

       If you didn't intend this JVM arg to be specified, you can turn 
       it off in your project.clj file or your global 
       ~/.lein/profiles.clj file by adding the key-val

       :jvm-opts ^:replace [] 
       ********************************************************** 
--> Booting internal SuperCollider server...
Found 0 LADSPA plugins
*** ERROR: open directory failed '/Users/ilya/Library/Application Support/SuperCollider/synthdefs'
Number of Devices: 2
   0 : "Built-in Input"
   1 : "Built-in Output"

"Built-in Input" Input Device
   Streams: 1
      0  channels 2

"Built-in Output" Output Device
   Streams: 1
      0  channels 2

SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 44100.000000, driver's block size = 512
--> Connecting to internal SuperCollider server...
--> Connection established

    _____                 __
   / __  /_  _____  _____/ /_____  ____  ___
  / / / / | / / _ \/ ___/ __/ __ \/ __ \/ _ \
 / /_/ /| |/ /  __/ /  / /_/ /_/ / / / /  __/
 \____/ |___/\___/_/   \__/\____/_/ /_/\___/

   Collaborative Programmable Music. v0.9.1


Hey Ilya, I feel something magical is only just beyond the horizon...

nil
user=> (demo overtone-sketchbook.synths/pluck-saw)

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> (use 'overtone-sketchbook.synths)
nil
user=> (demo overtone-sketchbook.synths/pluck-saw)

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> (demo pluck-saw)

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> (require 'overtone-sketchbook.synths)
nil
user=> (demo pluck-saw)

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> (demo overtone-sketchbook.synths/pluck-saw)

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> Bye for now!
```

#### *REPL session 2:*

```
> lein repl
nREPL server started on port 52100
REPL-y 0.2.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)

user=> (use 'overtone-sketchbook.synths)
--> Loading Overtone...
  ********************************************************** 
       WARNING: JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may 
       lead to reduced performance. This happens to currently be the 
       default lein setting:

       https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/pull/1230

       If you didn't intend this JVM arg to be specified, you can turn 
       it off in your project.clj file or your global 
       ~/.lein/profiles.clj file by adding the key-val

       :jvm-opts ^:replace [] 
       ********************************************************** 
--> Booting internal SuperCollider server...
Found 0 LADSPA plugins
*** ERROR: open directory failed '/Users/ilya/Library/Application Support/SuperCollider/synthdefs'
Number of Devices: 2
   0 : "Built-in Input"
   1 : "Built-in Output"

"Built-in Input" Input Device
   Streams: 1
      0  channels 2

"Built-in Output" Output Device
   Streams: 1
      0  channels 2

SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 44100.000000, driver's block size = 512
--> Connecting to internal SuperCollider server...
--> Connection established

    _____                 __
   / __  /_  _____  _____/ /_____  ____  ___
  / / / / | / / _ \/ ___/ __/ __ \/ __ \/ _ \
 / /_/ /| |/ /  __/ /  / /_/ /_/ / / / /  __/
 \____/ |___/\___/_/   \__/\____/_/ /_/\___/

   Collaborative Programmable Music. v0.9.1


Hello Ilya, may algorithmic beauty pour forth from your fingertips today.

nil
user=> pluck-saw
#overtone.studio.inst.Inst{:name "pluck-saw", :params ({:value #<Atom@24fc9cde: 800.0>, :name "f", :default 800.0, :rate :kr} {:value #<Atom@449ec5ca: 3.0>, :name "d", :default 3.0, :rate :kr}), :args ("f" "d"), :sdef {:name "overtone-sketchboo96d/pluck-saw", :constants [0.0 0 2.0 3.0 0.5 1.0 50.0 100.0 200.0 1 2 -99 -4 5 0.001], :params (800.0 3.0), :pnames ({:name "f", :index 0} {:name "d", :index 1}), :ugens ({:n-inputs 0, :args nil, :outputs ({:rate 1} {:rate 1}), :name "Control", :rate 1, :n-outputs 2, :rate-name :kr, :inputs (), :special 0, :id 280} #<sc-ugen: saw:ar [1]> #<sc-ugen: binary-op-u-gen:ar [2]> #<sc-ugen: binary-op-u-gen:ar [3]> #<sc-ugen: saw:ar [4]> #<sc-ugen: white-noise:ar [0]> #<sc-ugen: env-gen:kr [0]> #<sc-ugen: binary-op-u-gen:ar [2]> #<sc-ugen: binary-op-u-gen:kr [1]> #<sc-ugen: pluck:ar [5]> #<sc-ugen: binary-op-u-gen:ar [11]> #<sc-ugen: out:ar [12]>)}, :group #<synth-group[live]: Inst pluck-saw Container 31>, :instance-group #<synth-group[live]: Inst pluck-saw 32>, :fx-group #<synth-group[live]: Inst pluck-saw FX 33>, :mixer #<synth-node[live]: overtone.stu547/mono-inst-mixer 34>, :bus #<audio-bus: No Name, mono, id 50>, :fx-chain [], :volume #<Atom@6e9cebcc: 1.0>, :pan #<Atom@3cd6d0: 0.0>, :n-chans 1}
user=> (demo pluck-saw)

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: demo in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1) 
user=> (overtone.live/demo pluck-saw)

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
user=> Bye for now!
```

Am I missing something very basic?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

firstly, it would help hugely if you could make your question much simpler and succinct so that it's easy to identify possible solutions.

Also, thanks for giving Overtone a try - sorry that things aren't immediately clear. There's a *lot* going on here, so expect to ask a few questions on your way :-)

However, looking at your two REPL excerpts it's clear that you don't yet fully understand three things:

- How Overtone uses Clojure's namespaces
- How synths are designed
- How to trigger synths

Let me briefly discuss each of these, and hopefully they'll shed some light on what's going on.

Firstly, Overtone's use of Clojure's namespaces. When you `use` `overtone.live` what Overtone is doing is importing all of Overtone's public API functions into your *current* namespace. This means that once this operation is completed, all of the public API will be available to you - i.e. `demo`, `defsynth`, `sin-osc` etc.

In your second REPL example, the first thing you try to do is: `(demo overtone-sketchbook.synths/pluck-saw)` which won't work because Clojure doesn't yet know what `demo` is and has no ideas about your namespace `overtone-sketchbook.synth`. For it to know about these, you need to either `use` or `require` the namespaces. For more information, read up about Clojure's `ns` macro.

Secondly, Overtone's synths are designed by calling functions which represent parts of a synth (called ugens). Examples of ugens are `saw`, `sin-osc`, `lpf`. You can see a complete list of the available ugens in the Overtone cheatsheet: https://github.com/overtone/overtone/raw/master/docs/cheatsheet/overtone-cheat-sheet.pdf

`demo` is a macro that allows you to pass in a (partial) synthdef and to play it:

- `(demo (sin-osc))`
- `(demo (sin-osc 440))`

Note that ugens are functions in order to allow you to pass parameters to modify their behaviour (such as the 440 hz param to the `sin-osc` ugen).

It's also important to note that ugens cannot (currently) be treated the same as synths. A ugen is a component of a synth, a synth is a tree of ugens. Which leads me on to the third issue - you were trying to `demo` the `pluck-saw` synth. This is a synth which has already been designed and may only be triggered. To trigger a synth, simply call it as a function:

`(pluck-saw)`

You can also pass params (if the design permits them) to the synth trigger function.

So to summarise:

- Use Clojure's `ns` macros load external namespaces, and pull in functions to make them available. For Overtone's default API you need to pull in either `overtone.live` or `overtone.core` (the first boots a server if one isn't already booted).
- Synths are trees of ugens. Ugens are standard Clojure functions and return data-structures which are understood by the macros `demo` and `defsynth`. You can pass arguments to the ugen functions to specify their behaviour.
- Synths are not ugens. Calling a ugen function returns a data structure which can be used in a synth design. Calling a synth as a function triggers (i.e. plays) that synth.

Finally, do come and join us on the mailing list - we'd love to see what you're doing (and planning to do) with Overtone and share our passion with you:

http://groups.google.com/group/overtone/

Answer (score 1):

Try: `(demo 'overtone-sketchbook.synths/pluck-saw)`

I'm still getting errors with your code I don't understand, but that will get you farther.